# Does the root user need to explicitly grant privileges for the MYSQL event?

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL version 8 and I want to know whether root user(super user) of MYSQL need to specify grant for event for creating MYSQL event. Or is it already given to root user?
like this-

```
GRANT EVENT ON myschema.* TO root@localhost;
```

Comment: The `root` account can do anything. They're root 

Comment: that means root user has all privileges?

Comment: `root` user is regilar user. If it is one created during server installation then it has complete privileges list, but then its permissions may be easily altered, and it may be removed at all - its presence really makes no sense, any other user may be complete admin.

Comment: `root` has all privileges, *however* you should also **not use `root` for regular access** and instead have more limited accounts for that purpose.